# PopSQL + MySQL. The 'Run' Button doesn't seem to be working (Not Clickable)?

Tags: mysql, macos, popsql

I'm using PopSQL to write out my SQL queries, with MySQL, however I'm not able to 'Run' any of the code using PopSQL.  I'm on a Mac.  Does anyone know how to resolve this?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same issue and was able to resolve it by:

1. Click the drop down where it says Giraffe on the top left of your screen
2. Click Manage Connections
3. Make sure you've entered the Username "root" and Password: "password" (unless you used a different password).

I am also doing the same tutorial. I came across something that said the username and password are optional, but entering them is what allowed me to connect and run the query.